# VBA Using FileDialog as Folder Path in a Loop

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a copy of a workbook that I have, based on list of IDs. I have got this to work OK if I hard code the path, however I can't figure out how to do this where specifying the path using msoFileDialogFolderPicker.

I have tried a number of variations depending on what I have found online and have got as far as below but stuck. Help appreciated.

```
Dim xFilepath As Variant
Dim xFilename As String
xFilepath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFilename = Range("Table9[ProgramID]") & " Product Financial Allocation" & ".xlsb"

With xFilepath
    .Title = "Choose Destination"
    .SHOW
    mypath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

mypath = mypath

Sheets("FILES").Range("A3").Select

  For i = 1 To 3

Sheets("FILES").Range("A" & i).copy Sheets("TEMPLATE").Range("Table9[ProgramID]")

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=mypath & Filename
        FileFormat = 50

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=mypath & Filename

    Call DeleteQueries

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

  Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code can be used to select folder and then you can append the folder path with file name.

```
Sub ChooseFolder()
Dim sFolder As String
    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    Filename = "Test.xlsx"
    Filepath = sFolder + "\" + Filename
    If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
        MsgBox Filepath 'Use this for further processing
    End If
End Sub
```

Following code can be used select single file.

```
Private Sub ChooseFile()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xlsx"

      If .Show = True Then
        txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
      End If
   End With
   MsgBox txtFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. What I am trying to do is use   
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)   to set the path at the start of the loop, which would then be referenced for all files that are created. Where as I am not sure what the above does exactly? could you explain?
Thanks 
Scott